# Index Out of Bounds exception in a big program

Tags: java

I'm writing quite a big program that is suppossed to display the following output:

---student------grade---letter grade

---Student1-----89.37------B

And so on for 6 students + Min, max, and mean of all grades

---

Then it displays a window with another output :

A ** (*'s is number of A's among all students)

Min, max, and mean of all grades

---

I encounter the following error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

**The code compiles but does not run well, I can't find why the error appears. I would be very grateful for any help.
Thank you!**

---

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GradeCalculator extends java.lang.Object {

private static int[][] gradesMatrix = {
    {90, 100, 95, 80, 80, 90, 90, 100, 90, 87, 85, 2},
    {100, 90, 98, 100, 89, 92, 90, 100, 80, 90, 92, 5},
    {95, 86, 80, 95, 85, 80, 60, 65, 70, 76, 62, 2},
    {70, 50, 85, 70, 60, 72, 70, 80, 100, 68, 71, 0},
    {60, 47, 50, 60, 75, 60, 80, 70, 70, 45, 58, 3},
    {100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 95, 90, 100, 90, 96, 89, 5}
    };
private int[] letterCounts= {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
private static char[] letterGrades = new char[5] ;
private double[] numberGrades = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};;


public GradeCalculator() {


}

public void letterGrades() {

    for (int k = 0; k < gradesMatrix.length; k++) {

        if (numberGrades[k] > 89.5)
        {
            letterGrades[k] = 'A';
        }
        else if (80.5 < numberGrades[k] || numberGrades[k] <= 89.5)
        {
            letterGrades[k] = 'B';
        }
        else if (69.5 < numberGrades[k] || numberGrades[k] <= 80.5)
        {
            letterGrades[k] = 'C';
        }
        else if (60.5 < numberGrades[k] || numberGrades[k] <= 69.5)
        {
            letterGrades[k] = 'D';
        }
        else if (numberGrades[k] <= 60.5)
        {
            letterGrades[k] = 'F';
        }
    }

}

public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {

    GradeCalculator t = new GradeCalculator();

    t.totalGrades();

    String aStars = "";
    String bStars = "";
    String cStars = "";
    String dStars = "";
    String fStars = "";

    for (int m = 0; m < 5; m++)
    {
        if (letterGrades[m] == 'A')
        {
            aStars = aStars + "*";
        }
        else if (letterGrades[m] == 'B')
        {
            bStars = bStars + "*";
        }
        else if (letterGrades[m] == 'C')
        {
            cStars = cStars + "*";
        }
        else if (letterGrades[m] == 'D')
        {
            dStars = dStars + "*";
        }
        else if (letterGrades[m] == 'F')
        {
            fStars = fStars + "*";
        }
    }

    String message = String.format("A  %s\nB  %s\nC  %s\nD  %s\nF %s\nMin: %f\nMax: %f\nMean: %f\n",
        aStars, bStars, cStars, dStars, fStars, t.minGrade(), t.maxGrade(), t.meanGrade());

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, message,
                     "Grade Calculator",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

}

public double maxGrade() {

    double maxGrade = 0;

    for (int a = 0; a < numberGrades.length; a++)
    {
        if (numberGrades[a] > maxGrade)
        {
            maxGrade = numberGrades[a];
        }
    }
    return maxGrade;
}

public double meanGrade() {

    double meanGrade;
    meanGrade = (numberGrades[0] + numberGrades[1] + numberGrades[2] +
        + numberGrades[3] + numberGrades[4] + numberGrades[5])/6.0;


    return meanGrade;
}

public double minGrade() {

    double minGrade = 150.0;

    for (int b = 0; b < numberGrades.length; b++)
    {
        if (numberGrades[b] < minGrade)
        {
            minGrade = numberGrades[b];
        }
    }

    return minGrade;
}

public void totalGrades() {

    int studentNum = 0;
    GradeCalculator p = new GradeCalculator();

    for (int i = 0; i < gradesMatrix.length; i++)
    {
        numberGrades[i] = Math.round((( ((gradesMatrix[i][0] +
            + gradesMatrix[i][1] + gradesMatrix[i][2])/300.0)*0.2 +
            + ((gradesMatrix[i][3] + gradesMatrix[i][4] +
            + gradesMatrix[i][5])/300.0)*0.3 + ((gradesMatrix[i][6] +
            + gradesMatrix[i][7] + gradesMatrix[i][8])/300.0)*0.05 +
            + ((gradesMatrix[i][9] + gradesMatrix[i][10])/200.0)*0.45 ) *//x
            100.0 + gradesMatrix[i][11]) * 100.0)/100.0 ;

        studentNum++;

        System.out.printf("Student%-7d %-5.2f  %s%n", studentNum,
                          numberGrades[i], letterGrades[i]);

    }

    System.out.printf("%nMin: %.2f%nMax: %.2fMean: %.2f", p.minGrade(), p.maxGrade(), p.meanGrade());

}




}
```

Comment: The exceptions stacktrace **tells you** which line throws it.

Comment: The output should tell you what line the exception was thrown at.

Comment: It is the second to last System.out.printf statement, but I don't see any errors

Comment: Kind of unrelated, may I ask what does ** in \*\*studentNum and letterGrades[i]\*\* do? Is this Java syntax?

Comment: @Kaifei - I made this part bold (that's where the problem is), but for some reason there are stars there. Sorry for confusing

Comment: The double asterisks throws a compiler error. I think it's a mistake with the Markdown editor. An alternative, less likely explanation is that he/she is trying to dereference a pointer and forgot it's Java.

Comment: @vision37 You can't do bold in code snippets. The way to do it is to use comments.

Comment: I changed it, it was a misprint on this website :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop index is based on `gradesMatrix`

```
for (int k = 0; k < gradesMatrix.length; k++) {
```

Yet you are using the index to access elements in `numberGrades`

```
if (numberGrades[k] > 89.5)
```

and `letterGrades`

```
letterGrades[k] = 'B';
```

`numberGrades` *happens* to have the same amount of elements as `gradesMatrix` (it's first dimension), it does *not crash* (although it is likely wrong). However since `letterGrades` has less elements than `gradesMatrix`, this results in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, when you attempt to access the *non-existent* sixth element (at index 5).

Comment: Thank you so much! I see now, I changed gradesMatrix.length to just 6 (there are 6 students). It solves the problem!

Answer (score 0):

`gradesMatrix` is bigger than `numberGrades` and `letterGrades`, yet you are indexing the three of them using the same variable (`i`) when you output the total per Student.

That is why it throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 0):

If you use lots of array and use the array in several dimensions, then you may lost the control of the array, for example you need count the value exactly to make sure there has no outofbound error.
I would suggest you can use a clear object-mapping to manage the data you use, try not use array directly. May be insert the data into a database will be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when uou are going to method **totalGrades** in for Loop we are  using
System.out.printf("Student%-7d %-5.2f  %s%n", studentNum,numberGrades[i], letterGrades[i]);

and **numberGrades** array has a length of 5 when in loop and **gradesMatrix array has length more than 5** ,so while iterating numberGrades getting value from index which is not there.